# Running a pure Mongo command within Node/Express/Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

How do I run the following command within my Node application?

```
db.users.update(
    { "username": "steve" },
    {  $push: 
        { 
            likes: [ { "user_id": "3" } ]
        } 
    } 
)
```

I have a schema setup via Mongoose but I'm not sure if it's possible to run this raw Mongo command.

Comment: You should be able to do that via the [mongodb driver](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native).

Comment: Is there an equivalent solution using Mongoose?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1):

[Updating docs using Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update) should help you. The following should help you update docs using mongoose:

```
Model.update(
    {"username":"steve"},
    {$push: {
            likes: [ { "user_id": "3" } ]
        }
    },
    //if you have any options mention here(options),
    //A callback comes here (optional)
)
```

Here is the syntax of update command using Mongoose for your reference:

```
var conditions = { name: 'borne' }
  , update = { $inc: { visits: 1 }}
  , options = { multi: true };

Model.update(conditions, update, options, callback);

function callback (err, numAffected) {
  // numAffected is the number of updated documents
})
```

Comment: Your link points to old documentation (Mongoose v2, current is v4). Latest docs on updating are [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update).

Comment: @robertklep thanks for correcting me. I have updated the link in my answer.